# Turing degrees inside the $\Pi_1^0$ class with top Medvedev degree

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, computational-complexity, turing-machines

I'm sure i have read that the following (or something that implies this) is true

> Let $X$ be a $\Pi_1^0$ class with top Medvedev degree. Then for every
> $x\in X$, there is $y\in X$ with $y<_T x$.

But i don't remember where. If this is true, do you know where can I find this or a similar statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can modify the proof of the Kreisel/Shoenfield basis theorem (see Theorem 3.7 in [Diamondstone/Dzhafarov/Soare](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-51/issue-1/%CE%A0-1-0-Classes-Peano-Arithmetic-Randomness-and-Computable-Domination/10.1215/00294527-2010-009.full)):

Let $T\subseteq 2^{<\omega}$ be an infinite binary tree all of whose paths are of PA-degree (this is equivalent to $[T]$, the set of paths through $T$, having top Medvedev degree amongst $\Pi^0_1$ classes). Fix a path $f\in [T]$; we want to find a path $g\in [T]$ with $g<_Tf$.

Consider the following computable $4$-ary tree $S$: a node on $S$ of length $n$ consists of a pair $(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha$ is a node on $T$ of length $n$ and $\beta$ is a binary string of length $n$ such that for each $e<i$ it is **not** the case that $\Phi_e^\alpha(e)[n]\downarrow=\beta(n)$. Clearly $S$ is infinite, so $S$ has a path $h=(h_0,h_1)\le_Tf$. But $h_0$ is a path through $T$ such that $h_0\not\ge_Th_1$, and since $(h_0,h_1)\le_Tf$ we have that $h_0\not\ge_Tf$.